# Convert some data into json format but not sure if its working

Tags: javascript, json, format

I'm trying to get the attributes of a div and trying to put it in a json format.
For example if I have a div and its attributes are:

```
api="something" data-page="5" data-tag="blah"
```

So I'm trying to put it in this format in json:

```
{"api":"getArticles","parameters":{"param1":"value 1","param2":value2... }}
```

Here's the code I've written so far, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right because its return [object Object]. How do I check if what I'm doing is correct and see the json array in the above mentioned form?

JSfiddle link:  http://jsfiddle.net/ithril/mCNbW/4/

```js
var arr = $("div").get(0).attributes, attributes = [];
var l;
var attrinames;
var attrivalues;
var api;
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i].name.indexOf("data-")==0){
        l=arr[i].name.lastIndexOf("data-",0)+"data-".length; 
        attrinames=arr[i].name.substr(l);
if(attrinames!="apicall"){
    attrivalues=arr[i].value;
    attributes.push({attrinames:attrivalues});
}
else 
    api=attrivalues;
}
}
var json=[]
    json.push({"api":api,"parameters":attributes});
alert(json);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divload" data-apicall="anything.php" link="" data-page="5" data-tag="stuff">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify(data)` will serialize the data contained within the Object.

See updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mCNbW/6/).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `alert(variable)`. Use [`console.log(variable)`](http://jsfiddle.net/mCNbW/5/) and use a debugger instead. Hit F12 and view the console tab to see the results of `console.log()`. Also, I'd avoid naming a variable `json` because there is a global object named `JSON`.

Answer (score 0):

Build the JS object whatever you want, then pass it to a JSON stringtifier, like this one:
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Don't try to build yourself a stringfier, because you will make mistakes, is best to use libraries or something builting.

JSON format is text, and you are building a object, you need to serialize that object to text using the json format.

Normally it will look like that:

`JSON.stringify(data)`